# SBS Fax Server troubles

Tags: windows-server-2008

I deleted the fax printer in my SBS 2008 and I've tried many ways to recreate it. Can you give  some advice to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: (from http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/07/11/installing-fax-and-not-seeing-the-fax-printer-created-and-not-getting-an-error-either.aspx)

> If you ever delete the Fax printer from the server by accident, there
>   is no need to reinstall the Fax component, you can create a new one
>   from the "Printers and Faxes" folder, click on File, then select
>   "Install a Local Fax Printer". Please note that this option will not
>   be available as long as you have a Fax printer present, including ones
>   from RDP sessions. After you get the new Local Fax Printer, open its
>   properties, go to the Sharing tab, and share the Fax printer so
>   clients can connect to it.